# Java Code not working. Using loops to draw stripes on the US Flag

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to draw the US flag using java. I have pretty much done all this coding using lots of variables. It should be at least displaying the stripes, blue box, and the stars(ovals in this case). However, when I run the code through the compiler, and run it, all it displayes is a white background with a red stripe on the top. Could I please receive some help to see where my error is? I have tried everything.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class UsFlag extends JPanel {

int w = getWidth();
int h = getHeight();
int numberStripes = 13;
int numStarCol = 8;
int numStarRow = 6;
int stripeHeight = h/numberStripes;
int boxWidth = (int)(w*0.4);
int boxHeight = 7 * stripeHeight;
int starWidth = boxWidth/numStarCol;
int starHeight = boxHeight/numStarRow;

/*public UsFlag() {
    //ask user to enter number of stripes, star columns, and star rows
}*/


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();

    //Background
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    //Stripes
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberStripes; i += 1) {
        g.fillRect(0,stripeHeight, w, stripeHeight);
        stripeHeight = stripeHeight + 45;
    }

    //Blue Rect
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, boxWidth, boxHeight);

    //stars
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < numStarRow; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < numStarCol; i++){
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(5, 5, starWidth, starHeight);
            x += starWidth;
        }
        y += starHeight;
        x = 0;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(400, 400);
    window.setContentPane(new UsFlag());
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two parameters for the **fillRect()** method and the **fillOval()** method are considered coordinates (x & y) for the object you want to paint. This means that for **x** you need to place a integer pixel value as to where you want the **Left** edge of the object is to Start being painting from along the horizontal plain, and for **y** you need to place a integer pixel value as to where you want the **Top** edge of the object is to Start being painting from along the vertical plain. For fillRect() for example:

```
g.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 30);
```

[image]

The other two parameters are for the **Width** (w) and **Height** (h) in pixels of the object to paint. Use the the variable **i** from your **for** loop (y = i + 30; for example) to draw objects below one another. [Read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for more information.

Comment: Hint : just add the index times the height of the stripe on each iteration. It will increment the X value.